# R plot months for the first 2 years

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a data frame with data for max 2 years period on different objects:

```
ISBN   Date        Quantity
3457   2004-06-15  10
3457   2004-08-16  6
3457   2004-08-19  10
3457   2005-04-19  7
3457   2005-04-20  12
9885   2013-01-15  10
9885   2013-03-16  6
9855   2013-08-19  10
9885   2014-09-19  7
9885   2014-09-20  12
```

How can I plot `Jan to Dec` for the **1st year**, continued by `Jan to Dec` for the **2nd year**? 
I guess the idea is to normalize the years (to have 1st, 2nd), but not the months. (here's an example)
[Number of Items Sold over 2 Years Period Since Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJJJF.png)

Comment: Could you please provide the `dput()` of your data ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré here's a sample (it's huge): `structure(list(ISBN = c(9164203816, 9164203816, 9164203816, 9164203816...9197260002), Title = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L...3L,3L....2L,1L...2L), .Label = c("Det xE4r nxE5got som inte stxE4mmer", 
"LxE4r dig leva : Mindre stress -", "xD6pnas i hxE4else av min dxF6d
), class = "factor"), Qty = c(0L, 0L,...1L...0L...30L..1L..80L.. 1L), SaleDate = structure(c(1430200783.59,.... , 1104322312.383), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "")), .Names = c("ISBN", "Title", "Qty", "SaleDate"
), row.names = c(NA, 31745L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
data <- df %>%
  group_by(ISBN) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(Year  = year(Date), 
         Month = month(Date, label = TRUE),
         Rank  = paste(sapply(cumsum(Year != lag(Year,default=0)), toOrdinal), "Year")) %>%
  group_by(Rank, Month, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Quantity))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Month, y = Sum, 
                        group = factor(ISBN), 
                        colour = factor(ISBN))) +
  geom_line(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ Rank) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "ISBN") +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

---

Aussming the following `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ISBN = sample(c(3457, 9885), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2004/01/01'), 
                    as.Date('2011/12/31'), by = "month"), 
                1000, replace = TRUE),
  Quantity = sample(1:12, 1000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

This would produce:

[image]

Comment: It's close, but there are 2 problems (on my sisde): 1. The "Rank" gets to even "8th Year" , I guess because of the order (didn't discovered yet how to group_by "ISBN", order_by "Date") ; 2. I need to aggregate the "Quantity" by "Month" because by day is too detailed for 426,661 entries. So, would help me a lot if you could suggest a way to "group by", "order by" in R, and also include somehow an aggregation (with sum) in the suggested solution.

Comment: I need to update the previous comment. Adding arrange(Date) %>% , fixed the 1st issue with the years. I just need to figure it out how to do the aggregation. Anyway, this is the right answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @adlisval In the updated version, I did the aggregation by month as per your request. It's the `... summarise(Sum = sum(Quantity))` part. The plot now shows the aggregate value of `Quantity` by month.

Comment: Amazing! Very beautiful! Thank you very much. Sorry, don't know where to write this, but can you recommend 2,3 places where I could learn R as good as you? :) (at least these basic operations like group_by,order_by, aggregations, how to make them work together etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `lubridate` package for something like this. Note I am calling for dataframe `df` because you didn't give it a name.

So for example:

```
library(lubridate)
```

First format the date like so:

```
df$Date <- ymd(df$Date)
```

Then extract the month and the year:

```
df$Month <- month(df$Date, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE)
df$Year <- year(df$Date)
```

From there you can plot your results with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Month, y=Quantity, colour=Year)) +
geom_point()
```

Note your question could be asked better here as you haven't provided a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, but I don't know yet how much I should get in details (newbie). The project is more complicated and I didn't want to paste it all here, just wanted a sens of how it can be done. I'll try to edit the question, but the idea is to have a ggplot with geom_line for 2 years, ONE AFTER THE OTHER, "`Jan to Dec` for the **1st year**, continued by `Jan to Dec` for the **2nd year**" ,  not one on top of each other, colored by year. I need to color by ISBN and see in one plot 24 months (1st year, 2nd year), not 12 months.

Comment: Ok that should be easy enough. But can you explain the data a little more. Do you have more than two years in your dataset? Does it need to be discrete year intervals or overlapping? For instance, do you want 2012-2013 then 2013-2014 then 2014-2015? Or do you want 2012-2013 then 2014-2015?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I also thought it should be easy... I added an image in the question, where it shows exactly how I want the plot. As I said " the idea is to normalize the years (to have 1st, 2nd), but not the months", meaning that it doesn't matter the year as a date (i.e. 2013), but as **1st** or **2nd**. All items are recorder over a "max 2 years period", as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the 2 years period is different for each item (as showed it the sample data). It's not necessarily the same 2 years period, and periods can overlap.