# R compare current row to the next row (on same column)

Tags: r

I have something like:

```
ISBN   Date  Quantity
3457   2004  10
3457   2004  6
3457   2004  10
3457   2005  7
3457   2005  12
9885   2013  10
9885   2013  6
9855   2013  10
9885   2014  7
9885   2014  12
```

And I want to get:

```
ISBN   Date  Quantity Year
3457   2004  10       1st Year
3457   2004  6        1st Year
3457   2004  10       1st Year
3457   2005  7        2nd Year
3457   2005  12       2nd Year
9885   2013  10       1st Year
9885   2013  6        1st Year
9855   2013  10       1st Year
9885   2014  7        2nd Year
9885   2014  12       2nd Year
```

And I have this code:

`df<-df %>% group_by(ISBN) %>% mutate(Year = ifelse(DateYear > DateYear,"1st Year","2nd Year"))`

But I only get "2nd Year" everywhere, so I guess the comparison in `ifelse` is not actually comparing the rows in the column "Date". I guess I have to use a for loop, but was thinking that it's some other way in R. How couldI get to the result I need?

Comment: I don't understand what your criteria are for '1st year' and '2nd year'? Why does 2013 return to 1st year, and 2014 to 2nd year?

Comment: @Phil Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159194/r-plot-months-for-the-first-2-years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mentioned in the comments, should you have more cases, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(toOrdinal)

df %>%
  group_by(ISBN) %>%
  mutate(Year = paste(sapply(cumsum(Date != lag(Date, default = 0)), toOrdinal), "Year"))
```

---

For exemple:

```
#   ISBN Date Quantity
#1  3457 2004       10
#2  3457 2004        6
#3  3457 2005       10
#4  3457 2006        7
#5  3457 2007       12
#6  9885 2013       10
#7  9885 2014        6
#8  9855 2015       10
#9  9885 2015        7
#10 9885 2016       12
```

Gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: ISBN [3]
#
#    ISBN  Date Quantity     Year
#   <int> <int>    <int>    <chr>
#1   3457  2004       10 1st Year
#2   3457  2004        6 1st Year
#3   3457  2005       10 2nd Year
#4   3457  2006        7 3rd Year
#5   3457  2007       12 4th Year
#6   9885  2013       10 1st Year
#7   9885  2014        6 2nd Year
#8   9855  2015       10 1st Year
#9   9885  2015        7 3rd Year
#10  9885  2016       12 4th Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [windowing logic](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html):

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df_foo = read.table(textConnection("ISBN   Date  Quantity
3457   2004  10
3457   2004  6
3457   2004  10
3457   2005  7
3457   2005  12
9885   2013  10
9885   2013  6
9855   2013  10
9885   2014  7
9885   2014  12"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df_foo %>% 
  group_by(ISBN) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(
    ifelse(
    cumsum(Date != lag(Date, default = first(Date))),
    "2nd Year", "1st Year"
    )
  )
```

Comment: it's close but it gives:

Comment: sorry. it's close but it gives: `ISBN   Date  Quantity Year
    3457   2004  10       1st Year
    3457   2004  6        1st Year
    3457   2004  10       1st Year
    3457   2005  7        2nd Year
    3457   2005  12       1st Year
    9885   2013  10       1st Year
    9885   2013  6        1st Year
    9855   2013  10       1st Year
    9885   2014  7        2nd Year
    9885   2014  12       1st Year`  so after it gives the first time the right results 2004>2003="2nd Year", it continues by 2004>2004="1st Year"

Comment: @adlisval Are you sure that there are only ever going to be two years within each ISBN?

Comment: @adlisval Updated.

Comment: Thanks @tchakravarty, it worked. It seems I don't have enough credits (15) to post the vote, sorry.

Comment: Ah, for now I need only for 2 years, but it will be needed for more....if you know how to do it, please share cause it will be needed eventually. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @adlisval Please update your question (or better yet, ask a new question) with what you expect to have happen and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I forgot to address the previous comment to you

Comment: If you could have a look at this question, maybe would be easier to understand what I'm trying to do (and would be great if you have some suggestions, cause it seems barely touched). Please see the image included in the question, and consider that the period is 2 years for now, but would be great to have a solution that can include more years, in the same manner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159194/r-plot-months-for-the-first-2-years

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, and because I personally prefer such solutions, here is one using only base R, relying on `split` and `lapply` to achieve the result. Effectively, it loops over the different values of ISBN.

```
# examples data (note possible error on line 8, ISBN==9855)
dat0 <- read.table(text="ISBN   Date  Quantity
3457   2004  10
3457   2004  6
3457   2004  10
3457   2005  7
3457   2005  12
9885   2013  10
9885   2013  6
9855   2013  10
9885   2014  7
9885   2014  12", header=T)

# treat separately (loop using 'lapply')
datlist <- split(dat,dat$ISBN)
datlist <- lapply(datlist,
  function(x) within(x, Year <- as.numeric(as.factor(Date))))

# bind together
dat <- do.call(rbind, datlist)
rownames(dat) <- NULL
```

Output:

```
#    ISBN Date Quantity Year
# 1  3457 2004       10    1
# 2  3457 2004        6    1
# 3  3457 2004       10    1
# 4  3457 2005        7    2
# 5  3457 2005       12    2
# 6  9855 2013       10    1
# 7  9885 2013       10    1
# 8  9885 2013        6    1
# 9  9885 2014        7    2
# 10 9885 2014       12    2
```

Note that this method rearranges the data set in such a way that the rows are ordered according to ISBN. In addition, I didn't bother coding the `Year` column with `1st Year, 2nd Year, ...` etc. because I didn't really see a value beyond having a much simpler format like `1, 2, ...`.