# Compare row on same column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame as below:

```
x=data.frame(Time=c("2017-09-01 09:21:03","2018-05-05 05:58:59","2018-01-01 12:06:46",
                    "2017-09-01 09:21:11","2018-01-01 12:10:12","2018-05-05 05:55:50"),
                     First=c("X1","X2","X3","X1","X3","X2"),
                     Second=c("A1","A2","B3","A1","B3","C4"))
output:
        Time                First     Second
 1   2017-09-01 09:21:03      X1        A1
 2   2018-05-05 05:58:59      X2        A2
 3   2018-01-01 12:06:46      X3        B3
 4   2017-09-01 09:23:11      X1        A1
 5   2018-01-01 12:20:12      X3        B3
 6   2018-05-05 05:55:50      X2        C4
```

I want compare If current row to the next row(on same column),

And the Time difference is less than 5 minutes,

will generate a new dataframe and calculate the same number of times

And to get:

```
First      Second     n
 X1          A1       2   #(original row 1 and row 4)
 X2          A2       1   #(original row 2)
 X3          B3       1   #(original row 3)
 X3          B3       1   #(original row 5)
 X2          C4       1   #(original row 6)
```

Because the Time between row 3 and row 5 is more than 5 minutes, so different records.

And the Time between row 1 and row 4 is less than 5 minutes, so same records

I found an stackoverflow article, but I still don't know how to write it.

[R compare current row to the next row (on same column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174409/r-compare-current-row-to-the-next-row-on-same-column)

Answer (score 1):

I got there with `dplyr`. A bit difficult to get your expected result. I hope there is a simpler way. Maybe someone with better `data.table` knowledge can supply a `data.table` solution.

Basicly first create a group statement to calculate the time difference in minutes and if less than 5 mins set to 0. This makes sure that records within 5 mins get the same minute. Next get rid of Time and expand the grouping to include the minutes. Calculate how many records fall into these groups. Remove minutes from the grouping, do a distinct to get rid of the double records of X1 A1 and finally remove the min column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(First, Second) %>% 
  mutate(min = (Time - lag(Time, default = first(Time)))/60,
         min = ifelse(min < 5, 0, min)) %>% 
  select(-Time) %>% 
  group_by(First, Second, min) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup(min) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  select(-min)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  First Second     n
  <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 X1    A1         2
2 X2    A2         1
3 X3    B3         1
4 X3    B3         1
5 X2    C4         1
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1504250463, 1525492739, 1514804806, 1504250591, 1514805612, 1525492550), 
                                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                     First = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X3", "X2"), 
                     Second = c("A1", "A2", "B3", "A1", "B3", "C4")), 
                .Names = c("Time", "First", "Second"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try, and I think I need to learn more about dplyr.